# Redirecting a model's path to a different path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have the following in my routes.rb:

```
resources :universes do
    resources :planets
end
```

This creates a method, `universe_planet_path(universe, planet)`. However, the planet object knows which universe it belongs to, so I would like to have a `planet_path(planet)` function that can return the same url as `universe_planet_path(planet.universe, planet)`. Where should I put such a function such that, say, `form_for @planet` would be able to access it, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you don't want it as a nested route, don't define it as a nested resource. You can still use `belongs_to` and the like in your models without nesting resources in the routes. Alternatively, you could create a helper, or custom routes. But it really sounds like you don't want it to be a nested route in the first place.

Comment: I want it to be a nested resource. It's referred externally as `universes/1/planets/2`. That's correct. It's the only way to refer to it, in fact, because `universes/2/planets/2` is a completely different planet. But it's incredibly clumsy to have to use `universe_planet_path(@planet.universe, @planet)` when I could simply use `@planet` with the correct function put wherever it should be. Could you provide an answer with a helper? That sounds like what I want but I've been searching for an hour with those exact keywords and gotten nothing. Remember, there's no external route to make custom.

Comment: Referencing two different planets by the same id is quite unusual. Why and how are you doing that?

Comment: They're in different databases to ensure a complete separation of concerns. Clients with access to one database but not the other will never, ever be able to access the other unless there's a tremendous security flaw in the SQL engine itself.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of the question, in your application_helper you could create a function like so:

```
def planet_path(planet)
    universe_planet_path(planet.universe, planet)
end
```

Not sure about the `form_for` part though, that's a little bit more tricky.

Comment: I've gone spelunking in the Ruby repo and found where form_for (form_tag, actually) looks up the path. It's pulling in a hash from whatever is including the module, so I still don't know where to go to add to the hash.